# Problema em inserir dados em arquivo CSV

Tags: python, csv

Estou inserindo os dados no arquivo corretamente, mas quando eu abro o arquivo no Excel, os dados estão todos na mesmo campo na tabela.
Segue o código:

```
import csv

dados = open('DATA.csv','w')

try:
    writer = csv.writer(dados)
    writer.writerow(('Pais','Região','Status'))
    writer.writerow(('Brail','America do Sul','Emergente'))
    writer.writerow(('Argentina','Amerida do Sul','Subdesenvolvido'))
finally:
    dados.close()

print(open("DATA.csv","rt").read())
```

Logo após inserir esses dados, eu queria abrir no Excel, e aparecer uma linha com três campos contendo País,Região e Status, onde no caso seria meu cabeçalho da tabela, assim abaixo teria os valores. Alguém pode me indicar o problema ?

Answer (score 0):

Você queria apenas apresentar os dados na tela? Ou quer que após a execução do código ele abra o arquivo com os dados?
Se for a primeira opção, pode fazer as seguintes alterações no seu código:

Use o **with open** para abrir o csv e um laço **for** para printar os dados:

```
with open('\\DATA.csv', 'rt') as f:
try:
    csv.reader(f)
    for row in f:
        print(row)
except Exception as erro:
        print('erro: ', erro)
```

Sempre procure tratar possíveis exceções, pois facilita na hora de eventuais erros.

Comment: Eu quero que após a execução do código, eu abro o arquivo CSV no Excel e em cada campos esteja os valor que inseri com write.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa setar o delimitador para ponto e vírgula:

```
writer = csv.writer(dados, delimiter=';')
```

Uma dica: se você quer abrir o arquivo no excel, porque não gerar um arquivo .xlsx direto? Dê uma olhada nas bibliotecas [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io) e [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io).